# Describe a plane with z = ax + by + c

Tags: geometry, plane

I have three points in 3-D space.  I want to describe the plane defined by these three points with the equation `z = ax + by + c`.  How can I find the values of a, b, and c which do so?

Said another way: I have a plane described by the equation `z = ax + by + c`.  I have two points which I want to remain in the plane, and a third point which does not yet lie in the plane.  I want to rotate the plane about the axis described by the first two points, so that the third point is now in the plane, and then find the `a`, `b`, and `c` which describe this new plane using the same formula.  I've looked up how to rotate a point in the plane about the axis (and how to find the correct angle of rotation given the new point I want the plane to pass through), but I'm not sure how to work back to `ax + by + c` from there.

Said yet another way (this is the most convenient way for me to think about it): I have a function `f(x,y) = ax + by + c`, and I want to change the value of f(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) by a certain amount without changing f(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>) or f(x<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute coordinates of points (xi,yi,zi) to plane equations, and solve this [system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) for unknown a,b,c. Cramer's rule is suitable for three-unknowns system. If you have some math library with ready-to-use Gauss elimination, LU method or another solving methods, you can use them.

```
a*x1 + b*y1 + c = z1
a*x2 + b*y2 + c = z2
a*x3 + b*y3 + c = z3
```